Is Earth a place of eternal damnation and unlimited suffering
WARNING this is a negative view of life so if you are a sensitive to negativity I'd recommend not to continue reading.
Now, if we define hell like a location or state in which souls are subjected to punitive suffering, most often through torture as punishment.
Wouldn't be certain to think that we can be in a type of hell?
What makes me think this?
BIRTH / ENTERING
Nobody chooses to be born, you are brought by other people who are in hell already.
Souls are dragged into this existence, and since we are born, it hurts. Everything hurts. Growing hurts, learning new capabilities hurt. No mentioning, how vulnerable babies are.
LIFE
To live we need to consume other life, be it animal or vegetable, so we literally feed on other souls which would makes us evil. Nobody is born evil, but as you live, trauma, experiences, etc... develop a sense of evil (to a greater or lesser extent). So literally, the more you live, the more evil you become.
Also, we tend to like things that are evil like power, money, etc...
Anything we like is bad for us and anything that is good, it is hard to earn, for example.
We like food, but too much or the food we like is bad for us.
We like drugs, or money, or any other thing there is always a limit to how much good we can take.
However, for things that are good, like exercise, it is hard to achieve and generally, through pain.
Someone might say that life has good things but, of course it does. How would you keep anybody in this world if there is nothing good? That is the hook. Having good enough to keep you living.
DEATH
We don't know what is afterwards because if it is bad, anyways, we have survival instincts so we would like to live here as long as possible anyways and if it is good, nobody would stay here (alive).
Do you know any authors or philosopher who played with this idea already? has this been discarded from the philosophical point of view? I'd love to know people's point of view on this.

Hell is a human creation, like Heaven. Also the human life is a human creation.

this question is not philosophical (or meaningful for that matter) because hell is a mythological concept. you might as well have asked if we live in tartar, valhalla or olympus

"If you are going through Hell, keep going." - Winston Churchill.

There used to be a good comic called "Life In Hell". I like the Far Side one where a guy is whistling happily as he pushes a wheelbarrow through some place in Hell, and two devils are watching him. One says to the other, "We just aren't reaching that guy." Or the one where two guys are in a couple beds and one looks very startled, and the other says, "It's just a nightmare. Of course, we are still in Hell..."

"Hell is a human creation" do you mean the concept? the word? Not sure what's your point.
"this question is not philosophical" How come? I'm discussing if the philosophical concept of hell match with live on earth.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Life_in_Hell

Adults in general do not have the experience of eternity in the present moment. The concept of time dominates adult imagination. This is a good thing if one can moderate pain by action in the world. I once met a man who could go from heaven to hell in a heartbeat. His beautiful young wife lamented his suffering but did not blame him for it. I gave this advice: little by little try to generate more moments of heaven and fewer moments of hell. I try to take my own advice but conditions in my body or the external world sometimes dominate my intention to bring heaven to earth or heaven to hell.

Wouldn't any proper Hell consist entirely of bad things, in the same way that any proper Heaven would consist entirely of good things?  In our own world we have both good things and bad things, and that suggests we are neither in Heaven or in Hell (at least as those terms are traditionally understood)

There she stood in the doorway. I heard the mission bell. And I was thinking to myself this could be heaven or this could be hell. https://youtu.be/cZbKT-17Dk4. Hotel California lyrics: https://youtu.be/TPDjqZaJmjE?t=76.

We being in hell right now requires a lot of unwarranted presuppositions. First there is the question of who put us down here: we have no clue. As long as we haven't identified if something put us here and why, we might as well consider that we just happen to be  in the world as it actually is. As for the concept of "soul": we're supposed to be in that place were our souls are tortured, yet it's not demonstrated that we even have a soul. The pain you mention seem to make complete sense in a purely material world, it's an information useful to survival. Everything looks fine, so why doubt?

It's unfortunate that some regulars on this site have very opinioniated opinions which lead them to regularly close perfectly reasonable questions as "opinion based". "Hell" is obviously an imaginative, metaphorical term here, defined in the context of the question. The themes and questions addressed here and the implied outlook on life are definitely philosophical themes. The question asks for references. Existentialism was the single most important philosophical stream - important for non-philosophers and ordinary people - during the last century. And it's still relevant today.

In other words, please join me in voting to reopen.

@mudskipper "opinionated opinions" LOL! I don't think it is a good question, as written, but for the sake of good answers, I'll go along. Perhaps some editing would be helpful.

@ScottRowe Agree about the editing part - However, I'm a rather hesitant to do so, since I don't want to over-interpret or mis-interpret.

This outlook on life is usually expressed by existentialists.
Some existentialist, like Albert Camus in the Myth of Sisyphus, try to give a positive spin on what they see as the absurdity of existence -- the essential meaningless of life, the lack of any transcendent purpose or goal, the total indifference of the universe to our suffering, the ridiculousness of all our striving in the light of our unavoidable death. If life doesn't have a deeper meaning or purpose, we can simply say: "I don't accept that, I will still continue on living (and create my own meaning)." It's kind of a heroic gesture, but it seems rather reactive: it seems to only make sense as a last reaction to certain religious ideas of overall meaning -- ideas that had already lost their vital value -- but keeping a shadow of those ideas still alive... (If God is dead, why keep walking around with his corpse?)
There are darker, more radical existentialists, that don't find Camus' heroic gesture appealing. One vivid, fictional example is the protagonist in Dostoevsky's Notes from the Underground which is told in the form of diary, an angry rant - ridiculing the belief in rationalism.
The diary starts with the words

I am a sick man.... I am a spiteful man. I am an unattractive man. I believe my liver is diseased. However, I know nothing at all about my disease, and do not know for certain what ails me. I don’t consult a doctor for it, and never have, though I have a respect for medicine and doctors. Besides, I am extremely superstitious, sufficiently so to respect medicine, anyway (I am well-educated enough not to be superstitious, but I am superstitious). No, I refuse to consult a doctor from spite.

And later

I want now to tell you, gentlemen, whether you care to hear it or not, why I could not even become an insect. I tell you solemnly, that I have many times tried to become an insect. But I was not equal even to that. I swear, gentlemen, that to be too conscious is an illness — a real thorough-going illness.

Another dark, but real person who was very much in tune with such a view of life is Emil Cioran. Cioran is intensely sceptical of abstract speculation, ratiocination, system building, philosophical pretense and philosophical "theory"; he mostly expresses himself in lyrical, emotive rants and aphorisms.
If you are not able to read French, it's worthwhile to learn how to do so, just to be able to read a bit of Cioran. If you're able to read German - then you might be interested in reading Paul Celan's translation of some of his essays in "Lehre vom Zerfall" (The Doctrine of Decay). Wikipedia has links to some of the translations into English, for instance to The Trouble with Being Born.
The paradoxical effect of reading Dostoevksy or Cioran is that afterwards you may feel - strangely enough - kind of invigorated... Perhaps it's good to see your own innermost, purely subjective feelings mirrored by another human being. Though, honestly, I have to say that Cioran (and the underground man) can also become just a little too predictable and tedious, so I rarely reread them. But still, he may be a antidote (or immunizing agent) to a culture of toxic optimism and positivism that seems to prevail in some circles (for instance in large cooperations) :)

"afterwards you may feel - strangely enough - kind of invigorated..." Read Nietzsche.

As a teenager I found Existentialist writing to be completely unhelpful. But then a lot of earlier literature wasn't any better, and the Old Testament is pretty hideous in many places. Nonduality clears away the rubbish and makes the venture of life favorable. As for negative feelings, I go with the little blue book on that: "Depression is wrong because it infects others and makes their lives harder, which you have no right to do."

Do you think my point of view is existentialist? On the other side, I would see our existence the result of punishment. People in hell has been punished and therefore, if this is hell, we are being punished to live this live where the things we like hurt us and the good things are difficult to earn/achieve or whatever.

I do think it is an imaginative point of view similar to Cioran's - though Cioran was also inspired by both buddhism and manicheism (!) If you want validation, then read Cioran (or Dostoievsky). If you want counter-weights, then read for instance, the Tao Te Ching (Dao De Jing) or Alan Watts (The Watercourse Way). Literature (Dostoievky, Kafka or others) may be better, since it engages the imagination more and doesn't try to rationalize everything. For my development Camus was very important -- admirable because of his intellectual honesty.

I like the idea of a "genealogy of morals".

@ScottRowe I knew a therapist who said, "Depression is like flypaper. It sticks to the mother and her child. And they can't get it off." He looked down at his own chest and arms as if they were covered in awful flypaper. I don't think adverse moral judgment, efforts to transcend moral judgment, or talk therapy provide a sure
remedy for existential pain. I once told a Zen master, "I will either outlive my pain or die with it." When we cannot find a medical cause for suffering, or social injustice, then the source of injustice may be hidden or mysterious, and the pain seems to be existential.

@SystemTheory I used to stick a piece of tape to the back of my hat facing outward, when I went on walks in the woods. Deer flies try to land at the upper back place of moving objects, like a deer's head, because it works for them. They didn't bargain on tape being there. Another way is to walk with one hand sticking up higher than your head, and one by one you swat them all as they land there, where you can see them. You just have to make the perversity of the universe work for you.

If you were talking with a Zen master, then I sincerely hope 'you' did die. Feeling better now?

@ScottRowe - Jesus says, "Let the dead bury their own dead." Pain is for the living not the dead! I never understood the fascination some young people have with vampires (the undead) and zombies (the living dead) until I realized that during early life the child is full of vitality and by comparison the adults who conform to social norms are akin to the living dead or the undead. Most adults cannot fathom their loss of imagination compared to early life drama. I have never once met a therapist or Zen master who understood life-and-death. They all wanted me to play a role in their life-drama.

@SystemTheory you might like the books by Tom Brown Jr. His teacher said similar things about most people's lack of awareness and habit bound lives.

Some pessimist philosophers argue that humans are inherently doomed
Many of these aspects of life have been pointed out by existentialist and pessimist philosophers.  Pessimist philosophers typically don't assert that the world is "Hell" in a religious sense (as being an afterlife for the damned proceeding some other earlier life), but they do say that living conceptual beings like us are inherently flawed and that nature is inherently horrific in the requirements it forces on us.
In view of your interest in this topic, you might find it useful to read the book The Conspiracy Against the Human Race by Thomas Ligotti.  Ligotti argues that the situation is even worse than you describe and that the problem is not just circumstantial.  He argues that the root of the problem is that ---through an accident of nature--- humans have evolved beyond the simpler animalistic forms to possess a consciousness with a conceptual faculty that effectively forces them into a position of being at odds with nature.  The human consciousness and conceptual faculty (which Ligotti calls "malignantly useless") constitutes a "conspiracy against the human race" which Ligotti views as a mistaken mutation that humans have effectively been cursed with.  He observes that humans consistently engage in intellectual maneuverings that limit their awareness of the negative and horrifying aspects of their existence in order to be able to survive with a conceptual faculty that makes them aware of the horrifying circumstances of nature.  Ligotti views humans as a kind of natural "mistake" who are inherently doomed by the fact that they have evolved in a manner that is in opposition to nature.

It does seem that we learn by making mistakes. If we were perfectly in accord with 'nature' we wouldn't need to learn, and so wouldn't need consciousness. But, all in all, I'll take it.

Yes, philosophy has writings around the concept of suffering. Partly because in the history of humankind, many people were actually suffering a lot—not like the whiny neurotic modern city dweller who thinks life is hell because the Facebook news are so bad and there is inflation and global warming and their coffee store around the corner is going to close.
People lived in constant physical pain from malnutrition, lack of medicine, lack of security, lack of education (and many people still do).
As an example, from Buddhism (quoting some obscure site):

Now this, bhikkhus, is the noble truth of suffering: birth is suffering, aging is suffering, illness is suffering, death is suffering; union with what is displeasing is suffering; separation from what is pleasing is suffering; not to get what one wants is suffering; in brief, the five aggregates subject to clinging are suffering.

Sounds familiar? Still, this is sold with a resolution and a method to deal with it, yet the OP seems to prefer relishing in their own self-perceives suffering of life being hell without obvious solutions like "make an appointment with a shrink, you can afford it." So not sure if that answer counts.

I read that more than half the world's people now live in cities, so the whininess will probably only get worse :-)
